# reftex-toc freezes emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

Precisely as stated. I have tried both `C-c =` and `C-u C-c =` but in each case, it says that `*toc*` has been successfully built, and then all of emacs freezes before anything else is displayed.

Has anyone had this happen? I am using the latest version of AucTeX (12.2.0) and Emacs (26.3) on Mac OS X. So far as I can tell, the only relevant config options in my `.emacs` file for AucTeX are:

```lisp
;; AucTeX needs to be able to find where pdflatex is.
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/Library/TeX/texbin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/Library/TeX/texbin")))

(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
;; (setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
;; (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to get an error message, since emacs hangs before anything is printed to `*Messages*`.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but you may want to try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before starting what causes the hang. Then, one can hope—this is what I'm not sure about—that `C-g` will give you a backtrace telling what Emacs was doing at the time of the `C-g`. Other than that, I can't help: I've disabled refTeX on my system after a painful debugging session where I found out the problem was due to refTeX interfering with AUCTeX.

Comment: With reftex disabled, do you have a solution for `reftex-toc` (like `outline-minor-mode`) and/or for bibtex management?

Comment: Sorry. Except for editing .dtx files, I rarely use folding things. I just use `C-s`, `C-x C-x`, `C-SPC` and sometimes Emacs registers to find my way in large files.

Comment: @frougon - Can you please elaborate a bit more about the issue you faced?  Maybe dropping a line to `auctex-devel@gnu.org` describing the problem?  TIA.

Comment: @ArashEsbati I've kept a few notes, but since then have forgotten the small amount of refTeX I had learnt. I could maybe drop a line as you say, but probably won't  be able to explain very well. The core issue I had found was that when I enabled refTeX, the standard AUCTeX style for `amsmath` was apparently not being loaded anymore, resulting in error messages such as “Symbol’s value as variable is void: `LaTeX-amsmath-package-options`” when loading the AUCTeX style for `mathtools`.

Comment: @frougon - The issue you describe was only AUCTeX related and I think it was fixed with this [change](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=667f4e9351702ea1bd54c127bafa2dbf368b1401).  Please update your AUCTeX and the problem should be gone.  I recommend using RefTeX in addition to AUCTeX since it has many strong features which AUCTeX doesn't have.

Comment: @ArashEsbati I can reproduce the problem with AUCTeX from Git commit 097d04f6df6669a4543fc9f07ab97d4d2ec4c60b (Sat Oct 26 12:49:06 2019 +0200). I'll prepare something minimal and post to auctex-devel (when I encountered it, I thought refTeX was from outside AUCTeX, but I see both projects are maintained by the same people *now*). Thanks for your diligence!